# Forcing shallow copy with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source type which have simple properties and collection type properties.
I have a destination type which have exactly the same simple properties and exactly the same collection type properties.

Edit: I forget to mention that the collection type properties not only the same names but actually the exact same types, regarding both the collection types, both the item types

After I configure one simple mapping for AutoMapper like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MySourceType, MyDestinationType>();
```

and map an instance:

```
var destination = Mapper.Map<MyDestinationType>(source);
```

it seems I got a deep copy. 
I would not to have a deep copy I would like the destination and source collection type properties just reference copied:

```
Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(destination.MyCollection, source.MyCollection));
```

Comment: You will only be able to do a shallow copy on types of common heritage.  Also the point of AutoMapper is to do a deep copy.

Comment: This smells like a lazy abuse of AutoMapper; are you sure you're using it for its intended purpose?

Comment: @user3444160: Good point. I forget to mention that the collection type properties not only the same names but actually the exact same types.

Comment: @Clint it is not lazy neither abuse.  There are plenty of properties. Also the collection type part in the destination functionally read-only, so no need to deep copy.

Comment: Since they are the same types you don't need AutoMapper at all for a shallow copy.  obj1 = obj2 should do the trick.

Comment: @user3444160 this will just copy the reference. it won't copy `obj2` to `obj1`.

Comment: I think you may be getting your terminology mixed up.  A shallow copy is a reference copy.

Comment: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm

Comment: @tdbeckett I believe you are confused.  He wants to deep copy the root object but shallow copy the properties/references.

Comment: @tdbeckett: Shallow copy is not the reference copy. Btw reference copy is not even a term. It is reference _assignment_. Please google for shallow copy it will turn out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that AutoMapper documentation has no mention of this behavior. AutoMapper tries to deep clone the custom collection into a `List<>`.

```
interface IMyCollection : IEnumerable<int> // or class
{
}

class From
{
    public IMyCollection Collection { get; set; }
}

class To
{
    public IMyCollection Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Solution:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IMyCollection, IMyCollection>().ConvertUsing(s => s); // force shallow clone
cfg.CreateMap<From, To>();
```